# Vector operations of a neural network layer with different activation functions

Tags: neural-network, vectorization

#### Notations

At the forward pass of a neural network a neuron `u` at any layer is doing two sequential operations

1. Multiply all the weights by inputs then accumulate the results [MAC stage] the result in the scaler value `net_u`
2. Apply `F_act(net_u)` where `F_act` is the neuron activation function. The result is the scaler `out_v` that will be consumed by successor neurons

A block diagram for a neuron could be represented as the following image [source](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-7296-3)

[image]

#### Question

Now assuming an application that **does require** a neural network with different activation functions per layer. Such that at every forward pass each layer will have a `vector` of the `net` outputs of all the neurons at this layer and its the time to apply `f_act` on each element in such vector.

- In the case all the layers share the same activation function applying the activation function should be mapped into a single **vector operation** `SIMD`
- But what if each neuron [Or a group of neurons] does have their own activation function; Will this case be much slower to implement than the single activation function case ?

I believe it will be slower because whenever its time to apply `f_act` we need to invoke more than a vector operation [One for each `f_act`].

Am i getting this right ? or the overhead of invoking a vector operation for each `f_act` is very small that can be neglected?

Comment: Performance will be similar. It depends how complex your activation functions will be. It also depends of which programming language or ANN framework you will use.